# multiple case in one case, a get vowel but other letter not get why

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Find Vowel or Constant</h1>
<form>
<input type="text" id="user" />
<button id="btn">click</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>


        <script>
        var user_btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        user_btn.onclick=function(){
var user_input = document.getElementById("user").value;
var user_result = document.getElementById("result");

    switch(user_input){
        case 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u': {user_result.innerHTML="Vowel"; return false;}
        break;

        default: {user_result.innerHTML="Consonant"; return false;}
        break;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're defining the multiple switch case incorrectly. It shouldn't be separated by `||` instead by colon. I.e. `case "a", "b" : console.log('hello'); break;`.

Answer (score 0):

The case expression gets fully evaluated first. Non-empty strings are truthy, and a chained `||` will evaluate to the first truthy expression found. So

```
case 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u':
```

is equivalent to the first truthy alternated expression, the `'a'`:

```
case 'a':
```

So only `a`s will be detected as vowels.

You could put a separate case for each letter:

```js
var user_btn = document.getElementById("btn");
user_btn.onclick = function() {
  var user_input = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var user_result = document.getElementById("result");

  switch (user_input) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      user_result.innerHTML = "Vowel";
      return false;
    default:
      user_result.innerHTML = "Consonant";
      return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Find Vowel or Constant</h1>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="user" />
  <button id="btn">click</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

But `switch` is extremely verbose and can be error-prone. Consider a regular expression instead:

```js
var user_btn = document.getElementById("btn");
user_btn.onclick = function() {
  var user_input = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var user_result = document.getElementById("result");
  user_result.innerHTML = /[aeiou]/i.test(user_input) ? "Vowel" : 'Consonant';
  return false;
}
```

```html
<h1>Find Vowel or Constant</h1>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="user" />
  <button id="btn">click</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```